# Make image partially transparent in gimp

Tags: color, gimp

I want my image to have 60% transparency. How can I do this in gimp?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Just use the hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or go to 'Windows → Dockable Dialogs → Layers'. This should open the layers panel with an opacity slider, that you can slide to change the transparency. ([source](http://journalxtra.com/2009/09/how-to-make-a-semi-transparent-image-using-gimp/))

Comment: This solution doesn't work for Mac, BTW. The <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> equivalent of that shortcut does nothing, and the menus aren't comparable.

Comment: The shortcut listed does not work on Linux